# powershell regex match specific string w/o starting special character

Tags: regex, powershell, regex-negation

I have a string that I've matched with regex but that same string is commented out with a # sign in front and regex keep matching it which I do not want.

My Regex

```
BLTY:\w{8}:\w{8}:\w{5}\.\w{7}\.\w{1}\.\w{3}\/\w{3}\/.*\(\w{4}\)
```

String

```
BLTY:ENCQ0000:SERVER:TEMP.PPMQ8FE.Y.323/TCP/gtg23.dev.pmt.com(3213)-> only match this
#BLTY:ENCQ0000:SERVER:TEMP.PPMQ8FE.Y.323/TCP/gtg23.dev.pmt.com(3213) -> I dont want to match this
```

Tried

```
^[BLTY:\w{8}:\w{8}:\w{5}\.\w{7}\.\w{1}\.\w{3}\/\w{3}\/.*\(\w{4}\)]

^BLTY:\w{8}:\w{8}:\w{5}\.\w{7}\.\w{1}\.\w{3}\/\w{3}\/.*\(\w{4}\)

(?!#)BLTY:\w{8}:\w{8}:\w{5}\.\w{7}\.\w{1}\.\w{3}\/\w{3}\/.*\(\w{4}\)
```

Also if there's a less verbose/optimized way of writing this regex Im open to hear

Comment: How are you calling this regular expression from PowerShell? That makes a difference especially when using multiline characters (`^$`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need using lookaheads:

```
^BLTY(?::\w+){3}(?:\.\w+){3}/.*\(\d+\)$
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/mLl1Bd/1/).

**EXPLANATION**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  BLTY                     'BLTY'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (3 times):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ){3}                     end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (3 times):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ){3}                     end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /                        '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                       '('
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)                       ')'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```